# The implementation of arithmetic operations for vectors с#

Tags: c#, class, object

I need to create c# Vector2 and Vector3 classes, and i want to use "+, -, *" operators instead of functions.

For example, i need to Console.WriteLine(new Vector2(1,2) + new Vector2(2,1)); and it must type 3.000, 3.000

But all i can to do is create Add(Vector2 a, Vector2 b) function to do same thing.

So can i override + and other operations and how?

```
public class Vector2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Координата по Х
    /// </summary>
    public double x { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Координата по Y
    /// </summary>
    public double y { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Инициализация нуль-вектора
    /// </summary>
    public Vector2()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Инициализация вектора с заданной длиной вдоль осей X и Y
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">Длина вдоль (или против) оси Х</param>
    /// <param name="y">Длина вдоль (или против) оси Y</param>
    public Vector2(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Вывод значений длины вектора вдоль осей
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Строка с 2-мя занчениями - длина вдоль осей Х и Y</returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0:0.000}, {1:0.000}", x, y);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Длина вектора
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>double-значение длины вектора</returns>
    public double GetLong()
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Векторное сложение (и вычитание)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a"></param>
    /// <param name="b"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Vector2 PlusVector2(Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
    {
        return new Vector2(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static Vector2 operator +(Vector2 a, Vector2 b) { sum here}`

Comment: Can i have some more same question?
How can i do (-Vector2)?

Comment: You create a new method with the signature changed from `operator +(Vector2 a` to `operator -(Vector2 a`.

Comment: The .NET library already contains Vector2 and Vector3 classes that implement arithmetic operators, [including unary negation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector2.op_unarynegation?view=netcore-3.1)