# The implementation of '-' operation for own class

Tags: c#, class

[The implementation of arithmetic operations for vectors с#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61907066/the-implementation-of-arithmetic-operations-for-vectors-%d1%81)

I have new question about this theme.

I can "+" or do other operation with 2 or more objects, but how must i realize (-object), which means (new object_class() - object)?

Comment: Please show what you´ve tried already. I can´t see why subtracting some object from another one should have different syntax as adding. So where specifically do you have issues?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can add your own overload for the (-) operator, same as (+), as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading

Comment: Does [c# - Overloading +/- unary operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778939/overloading-unary-operators) answer your question?

Comment: `-object` *doesn't* mean `new object_class() - object` for any type, not even built-in types. BTW .NET already has Vector2 and Vector3 types in the `System.Numerics` namespace. Even if you need to create your own types, you can check the source of the built-in types

Comment: `-` in `-object` is an unary operator, ie an operator with a single argument, applied to `object`. It doesn't mean `new object_class() - object` unless you decide to code it that way. So, how *did* you code the operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different `-` operators - unary negation and binary subtraction. You can supply both:

```cs
using System;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo(42);
        Console.WriteLine(-foo);
        var bar = new Foo(8);
        Console.WriteLine(foo-bar);
    }
}
readonly struct Foo : IEquatable<Foo>
{
    public int Value { get; }
    public Foo(int value) => Value = value;
    public override int GetHashCode() => Value;
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Foo foo && Equals(foo);
    public bool Equals(Foo other) => Value == other.Value;
    public override string ToString() => Value.ToString();

    // unary negation
    public static Foo operator -(Foo foo) => new Foo(-foo.Value);

    // binary subtraction
    public static Foo operator -(Foo x, Foo y) => new Foo(x.Value - y.Value);
}
```